# Data Type Mismatch when passing DateTimePicker.Value

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, datetimepicker, oledbcommand

I was struggling so much with something that I eventually found out how to fix, but I don't know the underlying cause. If I add a `DateTimePicker` (in this case, `dtRecordBatchDate`) to a form and the user doesn't change it's default date and time and I pass its `DateTimePicker.Value` to a SQL command using `Parameters` property, I get this error:

```
using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Herbs_Stock (herb_id,batch_number,batch_date,quantity,cost,shipcost) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)", Program.myconnection))
{
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@herb_id", herb_id);
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@batchnumber", batch_number);

     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@batch_date", dtRecordBatchDate.Value); // HERE'S THE IMPORTANT PART

     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", quantity);
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cost", cost);
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shipcost", shipcost);
     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

> Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression

But if I add only one line before passing to the command it will be fixed:
`dtRecordBatchDate.Value=DateTime.Today`.

Why is it like so? This is weird because type of `DateTimePicker.Value` is `DateTime` not `DateTime?` and it's got already defaulted to `DateTime.Now` (or a few seconds before :)). I'm very curious about this.

Comment: What is the type of your `batch_date` column? What is the value of `dtRecordBatchDate.Value.Date` when you look in debugger? Why don't you use just `dtRecordBatchDate.Value` instead?

Comment: [_Criteria Mismatch_ usually means that the data you are trying to put into the database can't be accepted because the database is expecting a different type of data.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16297461/447156)

Comment: I have looked at all these things! they are all alright. Column is of type `DateTime` and so are `dtRecordBatchDate.Value` and `dtRecordBatchDate.Value.Date`. I think the issue is more complicated and perhaps it's a bug.