# Data type mismatch in criteria expression Error in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2013

Hi I am getting the above error in VB when attempting the following code, I have 3 text boxes on a form, after the user inputs a stock code I want the form to input the matching product group and product description in the relating text boxes. The code I am using is as follows

```
Private Sub txt_productcode_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt_productcode.Leave
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim connstring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:database
    Dim SqlString As String = "select [product group],[product description] from [stock] where [stock code] = " & txt_productcode.Text & ""
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connstring)
        Using command As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn)
            Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
                conn.Open()
                adapter.Fill(dt)
                conn.Close()
            End Using
            Dim MyDataRow As DataRow = dt.Rows(0)
            Dim x As Integer
            x = dt.Rows.Count
            For y = 0 To x - 1
                If y < x Then
                    MyDataRow = dt.Rows(y)
                    txt_productgroup.Text = MyDataRow("product group")
                    txt_productdescription = MyDataRow("product description")

                End If
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Each time I attempt to run this the form crashes, I get the above error message and the following line is highlighted in the code

```
adapter.Fill(dt)
```

Can anyone please explain why this is not working? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Data type mismatch in criteria expression." Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713299/data-type-mismatch-in-criteria-expression-error)

Comment: And here's a link to the other 318 duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%E2%80%9CData+type+mismatch+in+criteria+expression%E2%80%9D+is%3Aquestion

Comment: Awesome ill read through all 318 posts now, hopefully for a beginner like myself one of these may have some similar code I can understand. Thanks!

Comment: They are *duplicates*, which means you don't have to read *all*. Your case is not unique. A datatype mismatch error is caused by the same mistake. To quote [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178408(v=office.12).aspx): *"The criteria expression in a Find method is attempting to compare a field with a value whose data type does not match the field's data type."*

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå You do not get it.  Sometime after sites like this emerged, learning became *highly localized*.  Some people are only interested in the 1, 2, 3 steps involved in fixing *their* problem not understanding the issue in general - and apply it locally.  This leads to  "totally different" questions from the same person how to fix a data mismatch error in a SQL INSERT statement. BTW this is *hard work*!  You have to change the SO title enough to be unique so it will post and you have to ignore the "noise" of all those 320 similar questions it asks you to check out first.

Comment: @Plutonix Haha. Yeah, you're right. It's sad, but it's true. If the questioner cannot copy and paste the answer, it's not an answer. A great example is the infamous NRE. They glimpse at the dupe link and say *"Meh.. this doesn't solve my problem"*

Comment: What can I say, ignorance is bliss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to do is to remove the string concatenation when you build the command text and use a parameter, then you set a TextBox for the description instead of its text property. Removed also some useless code

```
Private Sub txt_productcode_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt_productcode.Leave
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim connstring As String = "...."
    Dim SqlString As String = "select [product group],[product description] " & _
       "from [stock] where [stock code] = @stock"
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connstring)
        Using command As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn)
            Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
                conn.Open()
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stock", txt_productcode.Text)
                adapter.Fill(dt)
            End Using
            For y = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim MyDataRow = dt.Rows(y)
                txt_productgroup.Text = MyDataRow("product group").ToString()
                txt_productdescription.Text = MyDataRow("product description").ToString()

            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's probably blatantly obvious that I have no experience in app building or sql but I am trying to botch something together that hopefully works. If you don't mind could you explain why when setting the stock code as a parameter it worked and why mine didnt?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. When you use a parameter you don't pass only the value of that parameter but also the type. In your case the AddWithValue decided that you want to pass a string. Now, a string value, when passed literally like you are trying to do in your concatenation needs to be enclosed in single quotes that you have missed. Instead, when the engine sees a parameter of type string, knows how to handle the parameter value. Always use this method when dealing with command texts and let the engine work with values (DateTime and decimal separators are another big problem with concats)

Comment: Now, for the purpose to answer this question, I have used the AddWithValue approach to define the parameter, its type and size. But be warned that the advantages of AddWithValue comes with an hidden cost. [Read this article](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) before jumping with both feet on AddWithValue

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I just wanted to say thanks again for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's likely that your SQL statement contains an error. Perhaps you're missing quote characters in the WHERE condition:

```
"… WHERE [stock code] = '" + ... + "'"
'                       ^           ^
```

Btw. your code is prone to SQL injection attacks, due to building the SQL command using simple string concatenation instead of using a parameterized query.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it did seem to be an issue with the SQL when stock code was all numbers, seemed to work when stock code was numbers and text. Strange.

Comment: Not strange at all. That's obviously some type of implicit type coercion in place. If you have a numeric value but don't specify it explicitly in the form of a string literal, it is inferred to be of a numeric data type (which `stock code` likely isn't). As soon as the value contains alphanumeric characters, there would be no choice other than infer it to be a string type.