# c# Updating access database using dataset

Tags: c#, datagridview

I’m writing because i have a problem with updating records in my access database. I searching the record using select(by id) and I display it in datagridview. Next I want to change it In datagrid view and update changed records using changed dataset. When im trying to do this I have  Exception:

> “OledbCommand.Prepare method requires all variable length parameters to have an explicitly set non-zero Size.”

This is my code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        connection = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
        connection.Open();
        string sel = "SELECT * from Table where Id=@Id";




            oledbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sel, connection);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", OleDbType.Char).Value = textBox1.Text;
        oledbAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        oledbAdapter.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        connection.Close();


    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    DataTable ndt = new DataTable();
    OleDbCommandBuilder scb;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        connection = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
        connection.Open();

        DataSet changes;
        changes = ds.GetChanges();
        ds.AcceptChanges();
        if (changes != null)
        {


            OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(oledbAdapter);


            oledbAdapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();


            oledbAdapter.Update(changes);
            ds.AcceptChanges();

        }
        ds.AcceptChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Saved");
```

Edit:
Thank you, you really helped me, but i have different exception now :D

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '((ID = ?) AND ((? = 1 AND Payment ID IS NULL) OR (Payment ID = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND CharNo IS NULL) OR (CharNo = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND CharName IS NULL) OR (CharName = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND MC IS NULL) OR (MC = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND Name IS NU'.

and when im added

```
builder.QuotePrefix = "[";
        builder.QuoteSuffix = "]";
```

i have

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

when im trying to update..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the datatype of the ID field and assign length to it.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", OleDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = textBox1.Text;
```

Comment: It helped but i have Data type mismatch now when im trying to update

Comment: Exception System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was not handled
  ErrorCode=-2147217913
  HResult=-2147217913
  Message=Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
  Source=Microsoft Access Database Engine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713299/data-type-mismatch-in-criteria-expression-error

Comment: yeah i know this exception, but im trying to change only one letter in one cell for example so it should work i think..